# DropDownList getting a blank selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a dropdownlist populated by code, directly from the database. But there's a selectable item with no value, at the bottom. How can I bind the data from the database purely / entirely to avoid getting this blank selection in the future?

```
   protected void DropDownList_OnDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            DropDownList ddlName = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlName");

            ddlName.DataSource = MyClass.NameList();
            ddlName.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddlName.DataValueField = "id";
            ddlName.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Check whether MyClass.NameList() returns the list with a blank record. If so, you should remove it from there. Otherwise you could remove the blank entry from the ddl once it's bound. But, that's bad coding. Bind only what you want.

Comment: no it just gets data directly from a view :(

 public List<View_Names> NameList()
        {
            var varName = from a in contxt.View_Names
                                select a;

            return varName.ToList();
        }

Comment: Ok. Instead of ddlName.DataSource = MyClass.NameList(); try var list = MyClass.NameList(); and see what's in list. I'm gussing the blank line is in there.

Comment: But how do I bind that to my dropdownlist? :(

Comment: IN MyClass.NameList you are having a record where name field is null, where you are populating this list, select records where name is not null.

Comment: Like this. var list = MyClass.NameList(); // remove blank lines here

ddlName.DataSource = list;
ddlName.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlName.DataValueField = "id";
ddlName.DataBind();

Comment: Your code is fine. Just debug and see the list returned by MyClass.NameList() if it contains any value with null or empty string.

Comment: Can u please show the NameList method.

Comment: I already truncated the table, added only **1** datum, and still shows the datum and a blank available for selection in the dropdownlist. I think the problem is in the dropdownlist. :( @Rex

Comment: Still the same. Sorry @Sam :(

Comment: Definitely the issue is in MyClass.NameList(). Try this to ignore null and empty values in your list. public List<View_Names> NameList() { var varName = from a in contxt.View_Names 
where a != null && a.Length > 0
select a; return varName.ToList(); }

Comment: a.Length could not be read and not in IntelliSense. I must be missing something. But i'll try where a != null @Sam

Comment: Then try where a != null && a != ""

Comment: return View_Names.Where(e => e.id != null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove your code declaration '< asp:DropDownList >' and type it again. This will refresh your dropdownlist from scratch, clearing all its reference upon deleting it. Your current dropdownlist may be taking a reference somewhere along the development of your project.

Comment: Oh. Sorry I can't help you yet about avoiding that blank in the future though.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure NameList() method doesnot return any null values.

Comment: Method in comment but ill paste again in more readable format

Comment: public List<View_Names> NameList() { ____________________ var varName = from a in contxt.View_Names select a;________________________ return varName.ToList();_____________ }